# With Svelte : How to put component style in a separated file but still scoped to this component

Tags: css, scope, components, rules, svelte-3

I'm working on a table component which one will be usable (included in a library when it will work correctly)in any of my projects.
As there is a lot of css rules related to this component I would like to put the style outside of the component svelte file.
What I did is writing a separate css file which I import in the component svelte file by :

```
import './table.css';
```

But in such a case I can see my rules in the built `bundle.css` file but these are not scoped to my component.
So I'm wondering if there is way of doing it as I would like or not....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> yes, when svelte-preprocess is set up, you can use `<style src="./table.css"></style>` in the .svelte file
> https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess#external-files

Comment: Please don't provide such external links

Answer (score 1):

To enable preprocessing of external .css files into your svelte components, add a reference to svelte-preprocess in your svelte.config.js, like this:

```
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'
    
export default {
    preprocess: preprocess(),
}
```

Then in your component.svelte, do:

```
<script lang="ts">
  let count: number = 0
  const increment = () => {
    count += 10;
  }
</script>

<button on:click={increment}>
  count is: {count}
</button>

<style src="./counter.css"></style>
```

Where ./counter.css is the file you want to import to your component.